# Is it faster to add an element at the beginning of a list with add-to-list than at the end?

Tags: elisp, list

I've noticed that some people use a `t` at the end of this code:

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
```

that `t` makes it append at the end of the list instead of the beginning.

Why is that? Is it faster for Emacs Lisp `add-to-list` function to append at the end than at the beginning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is always faster to add in the beginning (except that [`add-to-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html) has to scan the whole list *anyway* - as pointed out by @phils in a comment).

However, performance is never an issue with [`add-to-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html) which is only used to *customize* user options like [`package-archives`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Package-Archives.html) and [`auto-mode-alist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Auto-Major-Mode.html).

The reason to add to the end of an alist is to avoid disturbing existing settings.

E.g., I had

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ts\\'" . js-mode) t)
```

so that `*.ts` files would be edited in javascript mode, but I added it to the end so that as soon as Emacs came up with its own default mode, it would be used instead of `js-mode` (actually, Emacs uses `js-mode` for now but you got my point)...

Comment: Note in particular that performance isn't an issue because `add-to-list` only adds the list item if it's not already there, so it must *check the entire list* for a match regardless of where it's going to add to.  If it reaches the end of the list without finding a match then it has a handle on both the beginning *and* end of the list, and adding the item in either position is trivial at that point (whereas if you *only* knew about the start of the list, pushing to the start would be faster).